# How do I extend a javascript object that looks like: `export default { ... }`

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a file that does something like this:

```
import SomePlugin from '../Plugins/SomePlugin';

export default {
   ...
   watch: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(editor) {
         this.$nextTick(() => {
            editor.registerPlugin(SomePlugin)
         })
      }
   }
}
```

I would like to extend that `watch` so that it registers my own plugin instead of its native one.

Is there a way I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just define watch first, and then export it:

```js
import SomePlugin from '../Plugins/SomePlugin';

const watch = {
  // modify whatever you want
  immediate: true,
  handler (editor) {
    this.$nextTick(() => {
      editor.registerPlugin(SomePlugin)
    })
  }
}

export default {
  ...
  watch,
}
```